# google map markers - image with custom colors

Tags: google-maps, svg, google-maps-markers

I would like to use one marker in 100 different colours.  I could do this by copying and painting the a marker in 100 colours, but it would be easier if possible to make one transparent image and paint it at run time if possible, or building an SVG on the fly for each marker.  What are options for this?

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {            
                position: position,
                map: map,
                icon: 'http://example.com/mymarker.png
                });
```

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

this works...

```
         var SVG_icon = {               
            path: 'M  0,0,  0,-40,  20,-30 , 0,-20,  z',                
            // set custom fillColor on each iteration
            fillColor: fillColour,
            fillOpacity: 0.7,
            scale: 1,
            strokeColor: 'black',
            strokeWeight: 2
          };

        // create marker and put it on map
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLocation,
            icon: SVG_icon,
            map: map
        });
```

example of SVG generated flags

[image]